# Proof of definite beginning and ending of syllables where three or more consonants in between?

Tags: phonology, syllables

(Note: I am not sure on how to phrase this question, so if you can, please edit for clarity)

So, recently a question came into my mind about whether we can actually define where syllables begin and end in a situation where three or more consonants occur in between vowels, especially between words.

When there are only one or two consonants, we can usually say. For example there is a clear difference between 'me rant' (ignoring the obvious meaninglessness) and 'mere ant' or 'nigh star' and 'nice tar' because a glottal stop is inserted in the first example and an easily distinguishable open syllable is caused in the second, although quickly saying the second may also cause ambiguity.

My question however mainly applies to when three or more consonants occur between vowels, such as in 'cork screw' versus 'cork's crew' in between which there is no difference in pronunciation, even when spoken slowly, unless the speaker intentionally pauses between words. Here the distinction of where the first syllable ends and the other begins seems to be purely morphological (am I using the term correctly?), and you could divide them as you wish. Same thing, but slightly different, the popular phrase 'thank you' could be realised as /θæŋk.juː/, or /θæŋ.kʲuː/, or even /θæŋ.cuː/, in normal speed speech, they all sound the same. So, my question is whether you can define where one syllable ends and the other begins in this kind of situation (without looking at where the words draw the line) or is it just as the person wishes.

Comment: There’s no glottal stop in _me rant/mere ant_ when I say it. The difference there is that they have different vowels: /miː rant/ vs /mɪər ant/. In _nigh star/nice tar_, neither has an open syllable (except the _last_ syllable in non-rhotic dialects) – the primary difference is the aspiration of the /t/ in _tar_ and the clipped (shortened) quality of the diphthong in _nigh_. The same is true of _corkscrew/cork’s crew_: the latter has an aspirated /k/ in the second syllable (which also devoices the /r/), while the former does not – so yes, there _is_ a difference, even in rapid speech.

Comment: are you sure nigh in nigh star isn't open? How are you defining open in this case as you're clearly syllabifying it as nai.star (no ipa keyboard) to get the deaspiration

Comment: @Tristan Well, I suppose it depends how you define closed and open syllables. I consider diphthongs to close syllables (/aɪ/ = /aj/) phonetically in English, though I suppose that’s not universal.

Comment: as the off-glide can only occur after certain vowels, that seems to rather overcomplicate English phonotactics. An exception would be schwa off-glides in non-rhotic varieties which probably are best thought of as consonantal rather than part of polyphthongs, them being strongly associated with the phoneme /r/ in native speakers' minds, and allowing for a more concise explanation of both linking and intrusive r's

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't know, when I say them slowly, sure they are aspirated, but in rapid (and not even *that* rapid, just normal speed) speech, they aren't.

Comment: @Tristan I don’t see how (phonemic) phonotactics would be complicated by (phonetically) closed syllables. I’m not saying they are necessarily phonemically closed, but phonetically I’d say they are.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius I don’t have any actual statistics for this, but I don’t think that’s common. At least, it sounds very unnatural to me to not aspirate a word-initial consonant, and given how important aspiration is in distinguishing word boundaries, that makes sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the phonotactics are more complicated (whilst the phonemic inventory is a tiny bit simpler) because now you're positing part of the syllable structure that's V(J) but only certain V can be followed by certain J, rather than simply counting the diphthongs as single elements falling under V

Comment: @Tristan That can still be true phonemically. Counting them as single elements just pushes the difficult down a step, requiring an explanation of why some single elements consist of multiple elements, but only in specific combinations; regardless of how you look at it, there is a complexity that can’t be systematised away.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet 'nice tar', maybe, 'cork's crew', not so much. Actually, I just realised I don't aspirate the 'c' in 'crew' even when I say it alone, don't know whether it's just me being weird or not, though. Plus, in the situation of 'mere ant' versus 'me rant', I say them with the same vowel (again, I don't know whether this is me just being weird or not), and I have yet to address 'thank you' again, I feel weird saying it as though the last consonant was a palatal approximant rather than a palatalised unvoiced velar plosive.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius If you recorded yourself saying _crew_, I’d wager you could probably measure it and find that you do in fact aspirate the /k/ in _crew_ and that your /r/ is at least partly devoiced. The only variants of English I’m familiar with that don’t are some speakers of Indian English and various forms of African English (perhaps some Caribbean forms too). I agree, by the way, that _thank you_ is generally syllabified [θan.kjuː] phonetically. The phonetic syllable border doesn’t match the morphemic one there.

Comment: … by which I mean [θaŋ.kjuː], of course.

Comment: maybe . . . but it feels sort of conscious either way, saying it so much makes it sound weird and I don't think I'll be able to find out which I normally say subconsciously for some time.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet agreed, there is fundamentally a complexity there. Viewing (most) diphthongs (again excluding those with schwa offglides in non-rhotic accents) as single elements also has advantages when it comes to diachrony, and the alternations in strong verbs (syllable nucleus alternating with syllable nucleus is far more concise than syllable nucleus alternating with syllable nucleus and an infix)